# How to set Java ClassPath in Monodroid

Tags: java, android, classpath, xamarin.android

I get a Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError error when creating an Intent of a custom class (an Activity). According to [this tutorial](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html#.Th2ma2H86i9) this means that class is not found at run-time. It's certainly found at design-time as the project compiles successfully. I have tried manually setting assemblies' path at Project -> Properties -> Reference Paths but the error doesn't go away. I tried with a simpler project with a custom Activity on the same file as the parent activity and runs fine. Where should I set Java's ClassPath in Mono for Android or what should I do to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a classpath issue. You need to add the class to your manifest file, for example:

```
<activity android:name="yourpackage.YourClass" android:label="@string/your_title" />
```

Barry

Comment: If I place this between <application> tags I can't even get the application to start. If I place this somewhere else in the manifest I get the same NoClassDefFoundError error.

Comment: You must have made a small mistake in your <activity> tag because adding an activity to your manifest (correctly) should never cause a problem. Post the <activity> tag you used, and the exception you get at startup.

Comment: Thanks Barry. Since Xamarin got the control over Mono for Android again this week I brought the issue to the official mailing list: http://mono-for-android.1047100.n5.nabble.com/Unable-to-find-library-td4611576.html It seems this could be a Monodroid bug, they are investigating it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you haven't registered your activity with the manifest. You can do this manually, but the better approach is to decorate your activity class with ActivityAttribute, like this:

```
[Activity(Label = "Activity Label", MainLauncher = true)]
public class CustomActivity : Activity
```

Once you do that, the manifest entry will be generated for you.

Comment: I had done so without the MainLauncher attribute as my Activity is used in an ActivityGroup. It doesn't help either.